# imagettfbbox(): Invalid font filename

Tags: php, image, image-processing

```
<?php
$size = 12;//font height
$font = 'Arial';// your font
$char = 'Test';
$char = 'With W';
$char = 'without w but with p and y and q';

    $rect = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $char);

    $image_height =abs( $rect[7] );//do no respect bottom margin
    $imw = $rect[2] - $rect[0]; //as usual
    $bx = abs( $rect[ 0 ] ); // X offset 
    $by = $size * 1.25; // Y offset - we will use const LINEHEIGHT
?>
```

Can you help me with this error?

> Warning: imagettfbbox() [function.imagettfbbox]: Invalid font filename in C:\wamp\www\test\createImage.php on line 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font argument should be a .ttf file, not a font name. You can find a lot of resources for [fonts](http://www.google.co.uk/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=.ttf&btnG=Google+Search#sclient=tablet-gws&hl=en&tbo=d&source=hp&q=.ttf+font&pbx=1&oq=.ttf+font&aq=f&aqi=g3&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3895l5883l0l7762l5l3l0l1l1l0l629l1081l4-1.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=90b6c2bb9e65466e&biw=1024&bih=660) with a quick google search.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when using:

```
$font = './arial.ttf';
```

after I copied the arial file from 
"`(C:/Windows/)fonts`" to the directoty in which the php file resides.

Answer (score -1):

Beware of path. If you use pChart the examples work, but your file doesn't work because the path of font files.

Therefore you must replace `../` with blank.

**Example:** `../fonts/Forgotte.ttf` with `fonts/Forgotte.ttf`. For me it works